# Is it true that the JSX Fragment is just to say, add them to the parents as the last siblings?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

If we return in React / JSX:

```
return (
  <div> ... </div>
  <div> ... </div>
);
```

It will error out, state it must be a single element, so we can use a `React.fragment`:

```
return (
  <>
    <div> ... </div>
    <div> ... </div>
  </>
);
```

But I noticed these elements are just added to the immediate parent as children, or if the parent already has some children, then these elements are added as the "later" siblings of the existing children.

Is this how it works?  Basically it just add them as siblings of the parent node.

Answer (score 0):

`React.Fragment` **only** groups elements without adding an extra node to the DOM.

> But I noticed these elements are just added to the immediate parent as children, or if the parent already has some children, then these elements are added as the "later" siblings of the existing children.

Its the **developer's decision** on where the element will render, a counterexample:

```
<div>
  <>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>World</div>
  </>
  <div>Other</div>
</div>

// Results
<div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>World</div>
  <div>Other</div>
</div>
```

Or as components:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentUsingFragment />
      <div>Other</div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ComponentUsingFragment = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>World</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: so you mean it doesn't have to the "last siblings" but can be "earlier siblings"?

Comment: do you know if it is true you can do it the same as fragment or an array? It seems both result in the same DOM tree, but array would warn you that you'd better add a `key` to the series